# How do I align cards in center with MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a grid that displays cards using MUI, but the cards are 'stuck' to the left side of the page. I've tried `justify='center'`, `mx: 'auto'` and `alignItems='center'` but the cards stay stuck to the left. I'm sure I'm using some prop that overrides my attempts, but I can't find documentation that speaks to my issue. Below is the code:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, mt: 6 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
        {Array.from(Array(6)).map((_, index) => (
          <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
            <ProductCard />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Below is what React is rendering.

[image: what react is rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can to in grid like this:

```
  <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index} alignItems="center" justify="center">
     <ProductCard />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried your suggestion, the cards are still stuck to the left of the screen. Is there a style I need to import to the file? From mui I am importing: ```import { experimentalStyled as styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Box, Paper, Grid } from '@mui/material';
import ProductCard from '../ProductCard';
import { spacing } from '@mui/system';```

Comment: **Try adding display flex to the grid** i think you do not need any style to import from mui